# ruby win32ole click not working in internet explorer 10

Tags: ruby, click, internet-explorer-10, windows-7-x64, win32ole

I spend previous days desperately finding solution to very primitive internet explorer automation with ruby and win32ole object. I found many examples but none of it works. Please help!

**The problem is, that I can open explorer and fill in data, but I can't click on the button nor submit the form.**

this is my ruby code:

```
    require 'win32ole'
ie = WIN32OLE.new('InternetExplorer.Application')
ie.Visible = true
ie.Navigate('haiku.php5.sk/PHP/automaton.html')
    sleep(1) until ie.ReadyState == 4
ie.Document.All.textNaOdoslanie.Value = "tralala"   
ie.Document.All.sbmt.click
    sleep(1) until ie.ReadyState == 4
```

and this is my sample page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="form1" action="automaton-action.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="textNaOdoslanie" />
        <input type="submit" name="sbmt" value="Odosli" />
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I am feeling I am in the dead end, cause I tried almost all possible code combination. Please, do not recommend me watir, I have tried that too.

**Thank you very much for help.**

PS: Please also do not recommend other browsers, even I have tried them too (with watir) but no success so far

**EDIT:** I tried to use ruby 1.9.3 and it seems to work with watir. However, ruby193 and win32ole and IE10 still not working :(

Comment: Can you tell me the documentation of where you find this code.. It is interesting...

Comment: Hi! I found it here: [link](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/05/automating-internet-explorer-with-ruby_20.html) and here [link](http://magazine.rubyist.net/?0003-Win32OLE)

Comment: While I am doing `ie.Document`,getting error...

Comment: I've tried to reinstall ruby 2.0.0 to 1.9.3 and click is not working either :(